# dnssec-dsfromkey showing unknown algorithm error

Tags: linux, dns, dnssec

dsfromkey command to generate ds record with following digest types DSA/SHA1, RSA/SHA-1,DSA-NSEC3-SHA1, RSA/SHA-512, GOST R 34.10-2001 etc

I am using the following command

> dnssec-dsfromkey -a  keyfile

eg:

> dnssec-dsfromkey -a GOST keyfile

But its showing

dnssec-dsfromkey: fatal: unknown algorithm GOST

And I am using the bind version BIND 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-61.el7_5.1

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems misleading.

Watching the bind9 source code from its git repository you can see that the `-a` option in `dnssec-dsfromkey` is handled by the function `strtodsdigest` which is short enough to be reproduced below and as you can see, no traces of GOST in that, so no GOST for you (or anyone else with these sources)!

```
unsigned int
strtodsdigest(const char *algname) {
        if (strcasecmp(algname, "SHA1") == 0 ||
            strcasecmp(algname, "SHA-1") == 0)
        {
                return (DNS_DSDIGEST_SHA1);
        } else if (strcasecmp(algname, "SHA256") == 0 ||
                   strcasecmp(algname, "SHA-256") == 0)
        {
                return (DNS_DSDIGEST_SHA256);
        } else if (strcasecmp(algname, "SHA384") == 0 ||
                   strcasecmp(algname, "SHA-384") == 0)
        {
                return (DNS_DSDIGEST_SHA384);
        } else {
                fatal("unknown algorithm %s", algname);
        }
}
```

Now studying the change https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/commit/27593e65dc4f1565bb45d91eb561a504da627c41 released 3 months ago where GOST is completely removed you can see, specifically at https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/commit/27593e65dc4f1565bb45d91eb561a504da627c41#18b3c86fc6dac451f69355fe2f743d98b043255a that the above piece of code had previously:

```
#if defined(HAVE_OPENSSL_GOST) || defined(HAVE_PKCS11_GOST)

    } else if (strcasecmp(algname, "GOST") == 0) {

        return (DNS_DSDIGEST_GOST);

#endif
```

Which means that the `bind` you had regarding GOST support was dependent on how it was compiled and if the associated openssl/pkcs11 libraries had GOST support or not.

I guess your specific RedHat package was compiled without GOST support anyway.

So you will need either to find another package or compile it yourself with appropriate flags (`--enable-gost` at `configure` time), but not the latest source code because as I have stated above GOST has been now completely removed.

See https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01636/0/BIND-9.13.2-Release-Notes.html that says:

> Support for ECC-GOST (GOST R 34.11-94) algorithm has been removed from BIND as the algorithm has been superseded by GOST R 34.11-2012 in RFC6986 and it must not be used in new deployments. BIND will neither create new DNSSEC keys, signatures and digest, nor it will validate them.

Which prompts the question: do you really need to support GOST or could you switch to another algorithm?

Comment: Actually I am in a trouble. My registrar not support the digest type 1 and 2, Is it possible to use any following algorithm.DSA/SHA1, RSA/SHA-1,DSA-NSEC3-SHA1, RSA/SHA-512, GOST R 34.10-2001

Comment: See https://www.iana.org/assignments/ds-rr-types/ds-rr-types.xhtml, Digest type 1 is SHA-1 and type 2 is SHA-256. If you look at the page support for these two types is mandatory so a registrar can not claim doing DNSSEC without those. I think there may be another problem and a misunderstanding between you and them... The algortihms you cide are not for DS records.

Comment: See also https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6944 : RSASHA1 is mandatory to implement (and hence SHA-1 or SHA-256 for DS), and the other RSA based one are recommended. As well as elliptic curves based, that could be another solution, but implementation in resolvers can be a problem or not, see https://www.potaroo.net/ispcol/2018-08/ecdsafin.html